# Docker-compose v3.5 with pre-excisting network and static IP not working

Tags: debian, networking, docker, ip, docker-compose

I am stuck with an docker-compose issue that I can not figure out. I am trying to use a compose file with a pre-excisting network and a static ip, but I keep getting the message that the network does not excist (fyi: if I try it the docker run way with --network=dockernet and --ip=192.168.22.13 it works fine).

**Compose:**

```
 librenms:
    image: librenms/librenms:latest
    container_name: librenms
    hostname: librenms
    ports:
      - target: 8888
        published: 8888
        protocol: tcp
    networks:
      dockernet:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.22.13
    depends_on:
      - db
      - memcached
      - rrdcached
      - msmtpd
    volumes:
      - "./librenms:/data"
    env_file:
      - "./librenms.env"
    environment:
      - "TZ=${TZ}"
      - "PUID=${PUID}"
      - "PGID=${PGID}"
      - "DB_HOST=db"
      - "DB_NAME=${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      - "DB_USER=${MYSQL_USER}"
      - "DB_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      - "DB_TIMEOUT=60"
    restart: always
  
networks:
        dockernet:
          external: true
```

**Network:**

```
testenv@ota-debian-01:/*****/compose# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
1fd55d15c311        dockernet           macvlan             local <------
```

**When I run the compose file:**

```
testenv@ota-debian-01:/*****/compose# docker-compose up -d
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.networks: 'dockernet'
```

Somebody any idea? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a bit of help from my co-worker :). I had a lot of services in the yml compose file, I placed the "networks" service wrong under one other service, I placed it on the bottom of the Yml file on the same level as services. This solved the issue.